# Compile Rust application for Windows with cross and sqlite3 dependecy

Tags: rust

I'm trying to compile [my Rust application](https://github.com/buxx/trsync) for Windows with [cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross). I got this error :

```
   Compiling trsync v0.1.3 (/project)
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "/rust/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/rsbegin.o" "/target/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/debug/deps/trsync-36594acb4f0db109.trsync.69d5ec1a-cgu.0.rcgu.o" [...] "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "/rust/lib/rustlib/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/lib/rsend.o"
  = note: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `trsync` due to previous error
```

How to compile my application for Windows with `cross` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because it is not bundled by default with `rusqlite`. You could enable `bundled` through a feature gate. You will need to add this to your `Cargo.toml` file.

```
[features]
windows = ["rusqlite/bundled"]
```

or by linking to `winsqlite3`

```
[features]
windows = ["rusqlite/winsqlite3"]
```

Then when cross-compiling enable that feature in windows. Using the [command line options](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#command-line-feature-options)

`cross build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --features windows`

Comment: Hello @Netwave, thanks for your reply. This change produce this error : `feature 'windows' includes 'rustqlite/bundled', but 'rustqlite' is not a dependency`. Note my `Cargo.toml` include `rusqlite = "0.25.3"` as dependency.

Comment: @bux, it was a typo `rustqlite` => `rusqlite`, fixed it in the answer already :)

Comment: haha, missed that. Sadly, `cross build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` still produce compilation error : `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lsqlite3`

Comment: @bux, but, did you use the feature windows? you need to activate it.

Comment: @bux, `cross build --target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu --features "windows"`